# spark 1.0.0 DStream.reduce is not behaving properly

Tags: mapreduce, streaming, apache-spark

Has anyone got DStream.reduce working using spark 1.0.0?

I have some code which seems perfectly reasonable.

```
  val word1 = messages.map {
    word =>
    val key = word
    (key, 1)
  }

val wordcount = word1.reduce(reduceCount)

private def reduceCount(count1: Int, count2: Int) : Int = {
   count1 + count2
}
```

The reduce statement gets a compilation error: type mismatch;  found   : Integer  required: (String, Int)

Why would it have this complaint? reduceCount should just operate on the int count, and reduce should be returning the same type as word1, which is (String, int). I tried a lot of variations to get around this error, but it just seems to be behaving incorrectly.

If you call reduceByKeyAndWindow instead, then there is no compilation error.

```
val wordcount = word1.reduceByKeyAndWindow(reduceCount, batchDuration)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation `DStream.reduce` has the following signature:

```
def reduce(reduceFunc: (T, T) => T): DStream[T]
```

Semantically, it takes an associative function of 2 elements of the stream and produces one element.

Given `messagesDstream` is a stream of Strings, after mapping it like this:

```
val word1 = messagesDstream.map {word => (word,1)}
```

the type of `word1` is Tuple2[String, Int].  This means that `reduce` should take a reduce function with a signature: `f(x:(String,Int), y:(String,Int)): (String, Int)`.  In the code provided on the question, the reduce function is `f(x:Int, y:Int):Int`.

The operation you would like to use in this case it `Dstream.reduceByKey(_ + _)` as it will apply the reduce function after grouping values by keys, which is what a word count is about.

Comment: Hey, you got ahead of me. I just realized that the right call is reduceByKey(). I had the wrong lib, and did not find that function call yesterday.

Comment: @user1058511 If you consider the question answered, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @user1058511 PS: I see you've never accepted a question you've asked before. - It's part of the SO community dynamics and etiquette to accept what you consider a correct answer to your question. Some people will even refuse to answer your questions upon seeing that track record.

Comment: I had to google how to accept an answer. it seems redundant that I voted it up and still have to explicitly accept.